# Correct way of using element.addEventListener

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have a few JavaScript functions that behave as event listeners for an `<object/>` object which fires custom events. The object in question is the JavaScript API enabled YouTube player. The [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html) provides this example code for attaching event listener:

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
  ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
  ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
  // note: quotes used ----------------------^---------------------^
  // note: callback function defined in an arbitrary location
}
function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
   alert("Player's new state: " + newState);
}
```

However, according to the [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) examples I've seen elsewhere do not suggest using quotes:

```
function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
   alert("Player's new state: " + newState);
}
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
  ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
  // note: callback function defined EARLIER
  ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", onytplayerStateChange);
}
```

So which method is right? The first one appeared to work in all browsers but recently I notice strange problems and I wonder if those problems are related with the way addEventListener is called.

Comment: The function "onytplayerStateChange" is actually a "listener" which happens to be a JavaScript function and I cannot find any place where it mentions that the listener should be enclosed in quotations. So not to use the quotations should be the correct way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the addEventListener method is actually a method exposed in the flash player and not the native addEventListener, it really depends on the implementation of the AS3 code inside the YTPlayer.

I would go with the documentations and use the quotes

Comment: The `addEventListener` functions in fact look different. Is this behavior mentioned somewhere?