# create a javascript function programmatically

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Need this for the youtube api // the onStateChange callback functions!

I want to programmatically create functions which will listen to the "onStateChange" event emitted by several youtube player. Adding the listener works already:

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
  var ytpStateManager = playerId +"_StateManager";
  document.getElementById(playerId).addEventListener("onStateChange", ytpStateManager );
...
```

The function I need to create based on the playerId variable ("ytp_1", "ytp_2", ...) is

```
function ytpStateManager(newState) {
  ytpStateHelper(playerId , newState);
}
```

So the result for the playerId "ytp_1" would look like this:

```
function ytp_1_StateManager(newState) {
  ytpStateHelper("ytp_1", newState);
}
```

Works also but right now I need to add them manually for each player, which is not what I need. I want to create them automatically when a new player sends a readyState event.

My problem is that it seems like these functions need to be a global functions to work properly. I tried several options for days now. My problem is that I do not know how (if there is a way) to define a global function, incl. the function name, programmatically, based on another variable.

Its a bummer that the ytp does not emit an event which includes the state AND the player/target. Would make things much easier. All this is basically the workaround as I need all to do stuff on all stateChanges.

If there is a better/simpler way, PLEASE let me know :) Otherwise a solution for this question is highly welcome.

**Maybe there is a way to rerout the event, to make it more "accessible"?**

I read in the spec that .addEventListener also takes a object, so I tried to bind the event to a dedicated object. But again, it did not get triggered. Feels like I tested everything ...

**UPDATE**
I am now switching to the iframe player (from swfobject) because that one provides an event which includes playerId and state :D Yeahhh!! After spending week with the wrong ytplayer this feels like a great advancement. Also seems like yt wants us to use the iframe player which can dynamically use html5 when supported.

Answer (score 5):

You create a function that returns a function:

```
function createStateManager(playerId) {
    return function (newState) {
        ytpStateHelper(playerId , newState);
    }
}
```

Then you call your function factory when setting up the event listener:

```
var player = document.getElementById(playerId);
player.addEventListener("onStateChange", createStateManager(playerId));
```

---

**DEBUGGING**

I'm not sure why that's not working, but here is a debugging suggestion. I suspect you may not be getting the `playerId` on your `onYouTubePlayerReady` handler.

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    console.log('Player ready. The player id is: ' + playerId);
    var ytpStateManager = playerId +"_StateManager";
    var player = document.getElementById(playerId);
    player.addEventListener("onStateChange", createStateManager(playerId));
}

function createStateManager(playerId) {
    return function (newState) {
        console.log('State changed for player ' + playerId + '. New state is ' + newState);
        ytpStateHelper(playerId , newState);
    }
}
```

Could you try that, and post what you get from both `console.log` calls?

Comment: I tried this before and right now again but its not working for me. Point is at the time "createStateManager" is called the "playerId" and the "ytpStateHelper" variables come from the parent function but the newState is not defined at the time as this will be the ytp state when the event triggers.

Comment: It should work... Did you test the last version I posted (I edited the code soon after posting).

Comment: When I call the factory on a state change this will result in a lot of functions but none is triggered. The callback needs to be a function name and a function with this name needs to be created automatically. Otherwise trigger won't work as for as I have tested it for days now.
Tested it, does not work. I am now testing sth. in that direction.

Comment: That's strange, `addEventListener` expects a function reference as the second argument, and that's what we're passing on my example. If it works with a function name too, I don't know exactly why. I just posted a debugging suggestion, could you try that?

Comment: I have a lot of debug messages in the code already. I clearly get the playerId. console.log("=== onYouTubePlayerReady: "+ playerId); >>> === onYouTubePlayerReady: ytp_1 . As said this exact code works with the manually added listener functions. the second log does return nothing, the functions is never triggered, no matter how often I play/pause the ytp. Also restarted the browser, cleaned the cache, ...

Comment: Very weird. Did you try @epascarello's idea? Maybe the fn has to be on the global scope, don't ask me why!

Comment: It is weird and I really tried for days now. //.addEventListener("onStateChange", ytpStateManager ); WORKS //.addEventListener("onStateChange", window[ytpStateManager] ); DOES NOT WORK even though the windows object list the functions //
ytp_1_StateManager: function ytp_1_StateManager(newState) {
ytp_2_StateManager: function ytp_2_StateManager(newState) {
__proto__: Window

Comment: @alexJS: There's a typo in your example of what you tried. Do you mean `.addEventListener("onStateChange", window["ytpStateManager"] )`? Because otherwise you'd be trying to access the function by the name of the stringified value of `ytpStateManager`

Comment: It won't work because a YouTube player's `.addEventListener` actually expects a string -- name of the event handler (see https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Adding_event_listener). Heck, it does not accept underscores in function names too e.g. `.addEventListener("onStateChange", "myAwesomeStateChangeHandler_forPlayer1")` simply will not work.

Comment: @SalmanA Good to know, for some reason I assumed it was a regular event listener.

Answer (score 3):

1)You can create Function object  `new Function([params], "BODY")` 
So you can combine body of your function as string variable and put into as BODY

Example:
    var twoNumAverage = new Function("x", "y", "return (x + y)/2") 
    console.log(twoNumAverage(3,7))

2)And new can create dynamically name and BODY

Example

```
var globalObject ={};
var nameFn ='MyNewFunction';

var createFn  = function(object,functionName, Body){
   object[functionName]= new Function(Body); 
}

createFn(globalObject,nameFn,"return (arguments[0] + arguments[1])/2");
```

You can call your new function:

```
globalObject[nameFn](10,20);
```

Result: `15`

Please note that in body your function you can get params via collection `arguments`

Comment: Thanks for the idea but the problem is that I need to programmatically define the function NAME. Based on the function called I know which ytp called.
Just checked out the iframe api and it seems that one is better as the event provides state and playerId, which is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to create a named proxy function that executes another function with the context you supply.

```
function createNamedProxy(name, fn, context) { 
  var template = [
          '(function @name() {',
          '  @name.fn.apply(@name.context || window, arguments);',
          '})'
      ].join('').replace(/@name/g, name),

  result = eval(template);
  result.fn = fn;
  result.context = context;

  return result;
}  

// Example Usage
var anonymous = function() { alert( document === this ); },
    named = createNamedProxy('Named', anonymous, document);

// Will alert 'true'
named();
```

The solution above creates a function that can create and return a named function that executed whatever you'd like. If you don't supply context, it will assume the window object just like a normal anonymous function would. To create the solution you wanted you would do:

```
var varName = 'ytp_1';
window[varName + '_StateManager'] = 
    createNamedProxy(varName + '_StateManager', function(newState) {
      ytpStateHelper(varName, newState);
    });
```

Where varName could be any programmatic prefix you'd like. When invoking ytp_1_StateManager() you would pass in your newState value and the code would call ytpStateHelper with your variable name and the newState.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
window["foo"+"bar"] = function(){ console.log("foobar is called"); }
```

Comment: This just programmatically names it, it doesn't create a function which has programmatically-defined behaviour, which is what the poster is asking about.

Comment: so you stick it inside of the function! Answers do not have to be 100% of what the user asks. Plus this method is not great since it is flooding the namespace. It really should not be seperate functions, but the one function than can handle multiple cases.

Comment: As mentioned in a comment for bfavaretto this won't work. For some reason the "addEventListener" can not handle a window[variable] reference. It should work, I tried more than twice, it does not.

Comment: Apparently, addEventListener is not the _native_ addEventListenerl rather, it is a function exposed by ActionScript (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/8876441/87015). You must pass the function name as a string. This approach is therefore the best I think.